# Is Heaven's Lost Property season 3 canceled or on hold?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

In 2013, they announced there would be a 3rd season for Heaven's Lost Property. Not too long after, they also announced the production crew, and a bit after that an on-hold notice. After that, I haven't been able to find any information about it.

Is it still on hold? Has it been canceled? Or something different altogether?

Comment: it should become a movie, around April if I'm not mistake

Comment: shouldn't this tag under [tag:sora-no-otoshimono]?

Comment: @ShinobuOshino ah only knew it under the english name ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this picture on latest manga

[image]

and based on this [wiki page](http://soranootoshimono.wikia.com/wiki/Heaven%27s_Lost_Property_Final:_Eternal_My_Master), it should be airing on 26th April 2014 in Japanese theaters.

Comment: This is the second movie, not a third season of the anime. See http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-10-24/sora-no-otoshimono/heaven-lost-property-new-anime-to-play-in-theaters-in-2014, which states that the movie is replacing the previously announced 3rd season.

Answer (score 4):

The third season has indeed been cancelled; instead it was replaced with a movie that has just recently come out. [This is described by this ANN news article.](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-10-24/sora-no-otoshimono/heaven-lost-property-new-anime-to-play-in-theaters-in-2014)

**Sora no Otoshimono Final: Eternal My Maser**

[image]

**Quick Plot Summary / Overview:** The scene opens with the Zeus' destruction above Synapse, Tomoki calls for Nymph to return immediately; unfortunately Ikaros responds that Nymph isn't coming. Tomoki commands Ikaros to take him straight to Synapse as the Earth's surface deliberately vanishes. While flying towards Synapse, Ikaros tells Tomoki a story how long ago due to malfunction she was once ordered by a "boy" to attack Synapse out of desperation. Remarking a dying Sugata, Ikaros' body begins burning away because of a device installed within her whenever she approaches Synapse without permission. Having second thoughts, Tomoki orders Ikaros to go back but cannot since there is nowhere else to go to.

(Source: http://soranootoshimono.wikia.com/wiki/Heaven%27s_Lost_Property_Final:_Eternal_My_Master)